# Map integer(id) to text string?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, I'm storing a field called "type" as tinyInt, since I don't have that many types I decided not to create a table for storing the corresponding names of all these types.

When I query my table I want the types to be replaced by their corresponding names which I'm storing in php arrays. I wonder if there is a way to do this replacement inside the sql statement itself instead of looping through the results and do replacement on the returned result row.

Does something like this even exists:

```
select *, map(type, {1=>'abc', 2 => 'xyz'}) from orders
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The only way (I'm fairly sure) to do this is using a [`CASE .. WHEN ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) construct:

```
SELECT *, CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 'abc' WHEN 2 THEN 'xyz' END as stringType
FROM orders
```

You can also use the `ELSE` clause to specify a default, e.g. `CASE type WHEN 1 THEN 'abc' WHEN 2 THEN 'xyz' ELSE 'unknown' END`.

Comment: I like this one. It’s not the only way though: you can use a lookup table as well.

Answer (score 23):

Actually, in contrast to the answer by mathematical.coffee, there actually *is* another way in MySQL to map a number to text - at least if your numbers are contiguous:

> The `ELT()` function returns the *N*-th element of the list of strings: `str1` if `N = 1`, `str2` if `N = 2`, and so on. Returns `NULL` if *N* is less than 1 or greater than the number of arguments.

**Example:**

```
mysql> SELECT ELT(1, 'ej', 'Heja', 'hej', 'foo');
        -> 'ej'
mysql> SELECT ELT(4, 'ej', 'Heja', 'hej', 'foo');
        -> 'foo'
```

**Source:**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt

Comment: Very nice. This can also be adapted to be zero-indexed by adding 1 to the first arg. And non-continuity can be handled by adding empty strings, but that gets to be troublesome if there are lot of unmapped values.